# Still confusing with 's in the phrase

Tags: possessives

I have read all the threads on it and am still confusing with this case

Photographer's work is 24/7

or

Photographer work is 24/7

it answers "whose?" question. The work of a photographer.
Still which way to write it is correct?

Thanx a lot

Comment: **I am still confused** is more correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**A** photographer's work is 24/7" answers the question "whose". "Photographer work" describes the work, but does not answer the question of possession.